# R: shift each value in array based on algebraic sign (vectorized solution)

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I would like to shift each value in an array based on it's algebraic sign. If the sign is positive, the value should be shifted to the  "right", if negative, to the "left". We can visualize this as each value being "transported". If two shifts target the same index, I want to get the difference - that's what `b[i+dim(a)[1]] + a[i]` is for in the following code.

I've come up with the following solution, which is based on a loop and therefore pretty slow. Microbenchmark says it takes 603 milliseconds for a 2D array with 1,000,000 values.

```
dims <- c(5,6)
a <- array(15:-(prod(dims-10)), dim = dims) # create some data
a <- cbind(rep(0,dims[1]),a,rep(0,dims[1])) # pad with 0
b <- array(0, dim = dim(a)) # construct empty array

shift_by_sign_x = function(a){

  #shift by sign, > 0 = forward; < 0 = backward
  for(i in 1:prod(dim(a))){ 
    if(a[i] > 0) b[i+dim(a)[1]] <- b[i+dim(a)[1]] + a[i]  # sum values up
    else if(a[i] < 0) b[i-dim(a)[1]] <- b[i-dim(a)[1]] + a[i]
  }
  return(b)
}

shift_by_sign_x(a)
#microbenchmark::microbenchmark(shift_by_sign_x(a))
```

Does anyone have a good vectorized solution for this? I also appreciate non-vectorized solutions if they're fast. I'll be dealing with > 1k arrays with > 1,000,000 values each.

In the end, I'd like to do this for 3 dimensions (example treats the x-direction), y will be up and down based on sign and z in the third dimension. I'd appreciate a good idea how to do this without coding it seperately for every dimension. However I am equally grateful for a solution which just solves the problem described.

EDIT:

I used the solution of Grada Gukovic to implement this for a 3D array. The `shift_by_sign` function in the following code block is taken from Grada's answer. I will never have a negative value in the first column, because I will include a step which computes the abs() of each value before adding them.

```
dims <- c(100,10,40)
a <- array((prod(dims)*0.4):(-prod(dims)*0.6), dim = dims) # create some data
a[1,,] <- 0; a[,1,] <- 0; a[,,1] <- 0
a[dims[1],,] <- 0; a[,dims[2],] <- 0; a[,,dims[3]] <- 0

shift_by_sign_3d <- function(a, dimensions){
  b <- apply(a, 3, shift_by_sign)
  dim(b) <- dimensions
  return(b)
}
```

Comment: Why does your code shift the first collumn not once but twice to the right?

Comment: what should happen if you have a negative value in the first collumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? The code below is base solely on matrix operations and is much faster than yours.

```
shift_by_sign <- function(a) {
    #create a matrix of zeros 
    b <- matrix(0L, nrow = nrow(a), ncol = ncol(a) + 2)

    ar <- cbind(0L, a[,-ncol(a)]) # shift a one column to the right
    # this is ment to produce the action necessary for negative numbers
    #non-negative entries will be disregarded

    al <- cbind(a[,-1], 0L) # shift a one column to the left
    # this is ment to produce the action necessary for positive numbers
    #non-positive entries will be disregarded

    both <- ar > 0 & al < 0 # find indices in the shifted matrices, 
                            # where both shifts are necessary and you have to add the entries


    b[cbind(row(a)[a>0], col(a)[a > 0] + 1)] <-  a[cbind(row(a)[a>0], col(a)[a > 0])]
    b[cbind(row(a)[a<0], col(a)[a < 0] -1)] <- a[cbind(row(a)[a<0], col(a)[a < 0])]
    b[cbind(row(ar)[both], col(ar)[both])] <- (ar[cbind(row(ar)[both], col(ar)[both])]  
                 + al[cbind(row(al)[both], col(al)[both])])
    return(b)
}
```

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]   15   10    5    0   -5  -10
[2,]   14    9    4   -1   -6  -11
[3,]   13    8    3   -2   -7  -12
[4,]   12    7    2   -3   -8  -13
[5,]   11    6    1   -4   -9  -14
> shift_by_sign(a)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    0   15   10    0  -10    0    0    0
[2,]    0   14    8   -2  -11    0    0    0
[3,]    0   13    6   -4  -12    0    0    0
[4,]    0   12    4   -6  -13    0    0    0
[5,]    0   11    2   -8  -14    0    0    0
```

The structure `b[cbind(row(a)[a>0], col(a)[a > 0] + shift)]` functions in the following way. `row(a)` and `col(a)` return matrices of the same dimensions as `a` where every entry is the row or column index of that element respectively:

```
A = matrix(-17:18,6)
> col(A)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

Hence `col(a)[a>0]` returns a vector, where the column indices of all elements of a lagrer than zero are stacked by column `col(a)[a>0]` does the same for the row indices. `cbind` creates a matrix with two columns, that is used to modify the large matrix accordingly:

```
>  A[cbind(row(A)[A>0], col(A)[A > 0])] <- 0L
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  -17  -11   -5    0    0    0
[2,]  -16  -10   -4    0    0    0
[3,]  -15   -9   -3    0    0    0
[4,]  -14   -8   -2    0    0    0
[5,]  -13   -7   -1    0    0    0
[6,]  -12   -6    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: If yes I'll explain the code. Its easy to turn it into a function.